# Windows 8 remote shutdown

Tags: windows, windows-8, shutdown

I have two PC with Windows 8 with the same account name, same group, and with no password
to manage them.

I can access, for example, from one PC to another without problem
to manage remote files and to remote desktop sessions.

Now if I want to remote shutdown one PC from another I have **access denied** error.

I have also tried with `psshutdown` but no luck.

What's the problem?

Must I set into registry some keys that enable shutdown remotely a PC with blank password?

My firewall also have all rules enabled...

Comment: Wait... you have access to a computer via Remote.Desktop **without** a password being set on the target computer? That should not be possible. What username and password do you use to establish RDP-session to that computer? (You could use the same username and password with the remote shutdown command)

Comment: Just because they have the same username doesn't mean they have permission on any other computer other than their own.  What are you using to access the other computer

Comment: @Rik, yes I setted on Windows the way to access via RDP session with no password but only with user name via change setting in security policy.

Comment: Did you try to connect to the computer with [PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx)? I expect the same result as the `PsShutdown` but you could try it anyway. (for example `psexec \\computer cmd`)

Comment: BTW. If the PsExec doesn't work with the username without the password maybe you could create an (invisible) user with a password. You could run the shutdown command remotely for that user. `psexec \\computer -u user -p password shutdown -s`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your accessing through remote desktop connection

from cmd of the remote computer run:

```
shutdown -s
```

or if you want to restart

```
shutdown -r
```

Comment: No I want to shutdown from another PC.

Answer (score 0):

You can try typing `shutdown-i` in your search box and open the program that comes up. Then click add a PC, and type in the name of your PC. Then chose to shutdown or restart. Finally add the text you want to display. Hope this works!